# Program for drawing anywhere on your screen (Windows)

Tags: windows, drawing

I'm looking for a program that allows you to draw anywhere on your screen

But, I need the following features:

- Ability to move/pan the drawings you have made on the screen
- Ability to save the canvas to a document for later use
- A mode that allows you to use your computer normally, but still have the drawings you have made visible on top
- Ability to hide/show the drawings we made on screen, without having to permanently erase it

Optionally, but not required:

- Lines/shapes drawing tools

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t tried it myself, but OpenBoard might fit your needs. It’s free and open source.

http://openboard.org/index.en.html

Comment: OpenBoard is a whiteboard drawing software. It does not allow you to draw directly on your screen, on top of your active programs.

Comment: @whatthe Page 32 of this guide seems to indicate you can. http://openboard.org/download/Tutoriel_OpenBoard_1.4EN.pdf

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I've tried it out, and it does allow you to draw on screen, but it doesn't have any other features that I listed above.

Comment: @whatthe It’s ok. Maybe you could try Smart Notebook, but I don’t think that’s entirely free anymore. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it covers all the features mentioned but you should give Windows Ink Workspace try if you use windows 10. It's inbuilt in it and you just need to enable it from settings.